# Is this possible to create GCP load balancer use same instance in two different ports using unmanaged instance groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Run one more application server in single GCP instance(GCP compute engine based on Port).While Creating load balancer facing issue.

"Validation failed for instance 'projects/test': instance may belong to at most one load-balanced instance group."

Please let me know if there is an option for running two different services in a single compute engine instance.(May be services running with different ports).

like,

load balancer 1 path rule "/calander" -> test1 instance group -> **Instance 1 : x.x.x.x:8080**

load balancer 1 path rule "/sample"   -> test1 instance group -> **Instance 1 : x.x.x.x:8081**

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you can. You have to create 2 different backends which use the same compute instance group (CIG) or the same network endpoint group (NEG), but that redirect to differents ports

But, take care of your health-checks definitions. If one service is down, the VM will be considered as unhealthy and will be killed and another one deployed. The 2 services can come in conflict because of this.

You can't directly add the VM as backend. In addition, with a HTTPS loadbalancer (Global Loadbalancer) you can't expose the 8081 port on internet. I'm sure it's not your use case, but I prefer to remember this!